# Carregar do Banco de dados só quando estiver 100% tudo carregado

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Na parte de Portfolio, ao aperta em carregar +, vocês podem ver que carrega primeiro o bloco e depois as imagens com um delay de 1 segundo.

VEJA NO SITE: somospixel.com/test

Eu quero que só carregasse quando as imagens ja estiverem sido carregadas.

Função que pega os dados:

```
    function pegaDados()
    {
        var idUltimo = $("#buttonIdUltimoItem").val();
        jQuery.ajax
            ({

                url: "pegaPortifolio.php?id="+idUltimo,
                dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
                success:
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var pt1 = "";
                    var i = 1;
                    var ultimo_id = 0;

                      var size = 0, key;
                      for (key in data) {
                            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++; 

                        }

                     for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

                         pt1 +='<div class="element-item filter filtros todos  '+data[i].menu+'" data-category="transition"><div style="padding:2.5px;"><div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"><a href="#portfolioModal54" onclick="portfolioModal('+data[i].id+')" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/port/mini/'+data[i].imageM+'" alt="project 2"><div class="fundo-port"><h1>'+data[i].tipo+'</h1><h2>'+data[i].nome+'</h2></div></a></div></div></div>';


                         ultimo_id = data[i].id;

                         $("#buttonIdUltimoItem").val(ultimo_id);

                      }

                      monta_html(pt1);               

                }
            });
         filtrar($('#buttonIdUltimoItem').attr('class'));

    }

function monta_html(dados){

  $(".grid").append(dados); //joga o valor para um elemento html
}
```

GRID onde está os blocos ja carregados:

```
           <div class="wrap">
<div class="grid">
      <?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco      = '###';
$usuario  = '###';
$senha    = '##';
$link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
$idUltimoItem = 0;
if(!$link)
{
    echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC limit 6";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $sql["id"];
$idUltimoItem = $id;
$nome = $sql["nome"];
$tipo = $sql["tipo"];
$desc = $sql["desc"];
$menu = $sql["menu"];
$imageM = "images/port/mini/" . $sql["imageM"];
$imageF = $sql["imageF"];
    ?>
          <div class="element-item filter filtros todos <?php echo "$menu";?>" data-category="transition">

              <div style="padding:2.5px;">
              <div style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;">
                   <!--<a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" id="executaAjax" value="Executa ajax">-->
                   <a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" onclick="portfolioModal(<?php echo $id;?>)" value="Executa ajax">
                                            <img src="<?php echo "$imageM"?>" alt="project 2">
                      <div class="fundo-port">
                        <h1><?php echo "$tipo"?></h1>
                        <h2><?php echo "$nome"?></h2>
                    </div>

                      </a>

                  </div>

              </div>

  </div>
        <?php
}
?> 
</div></div>
```

BOTÃO

```
<div id="rend-more">
         <!-- <input type="hidden" value="0" id="ultimo_id"> campo oculto que armazena o valor do ultimo ID buscado no banco -->

            <button  type="button" id="buttonIdUltimoItem" onClick="pegaDados();" value="<?= $idUltimoItem;?>" style="width: 262px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid rgb(84, 128, 128); position: relative; top: 30%; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); cursor: pointer;  background-color: white;" class="todos">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:#4d8984;font-family: 'Gotham-Thin';float: left;font-size: 25px;padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 5px;">CARREGAR</h2>
                <h3 style="padding-left: 5px;float: left;font-size: 25px;color:#4d8984;font-family: 'gotham-bold';padding-top: 5px;">+</h3></button>
        </div>
```

Pegar Portfolio:

```
<?php

function fn_conexao(){

    $dbuser = "####";
    $dbpass = "####";

    try {

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###',  $dbuser, $dbpass);
        $pdo -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    } catch(Exception $e) {

        echo 'Erro na conexao: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $pdo;
}

function dados($pdo){

    try {   

            if(!isset($_GET['id']) or $_GET['id'] == null){

                $id = 0; //se o GET nao for enviado o for enviado como nullo , a variável ID pega o valor de 0

            }else{

                $id = $_GET['id']; //pega o valor passado via GET
            }

            $arr = array();

            $sql = "ALTER DATABASE portfolio CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $linha = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1){

                return $linha; //retorna o resultado da query

            }else {

                return 0;

            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {

            print 'Erro ao inserir os dados no banco: ' . $e->getMessage();
            $conexao = desconecta($conexao);

        }
}

$conexao = fn_conexao();
$dados = dados($conexao);

$dados = json_encode($dados); //converte o resultado para json

print $dados; //imprime os dados na tela
?>
```

Comment: Lazy Load https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/

Comment: @Lazy eu quero algo desse tipo aqui aquatro.com, você aperta em carregar ele demora mas carrega tudo ja pronto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras de contornar isso,

Uma delas é usar o lazyload que vai basicamente carregar as imagens conforme a necessidade.

Uma caracteristica interessante do lazyload que acho que dá pra vc incorporar para resolver seu problema é que ele troca a imagem por um gif de "loading" nesse caso vc pode carregar suas div com a imagem com "display:none" e deixar um espaço reservado ja pra ela e o gif de loading no meio, isso vai fazer com que seu layou não quebre.
Depois vc pode verificar se a imagem já carregou usando jQuery e verificando por exempo:

```
$('.seletor').complete
```

Isso vai dizer se já carregou.

Agora a lógica de como vc vai fazer isso é com vc =]

Comment: entendi, ele vai pré carregar a imagem, e quando for chamada vai aparecer mais rapido certo? mas funciona puxando do banco de dados?