# Pré carregar uma pasta com imagens

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma maneira de pré carregar uma pasta com imagens ao invés de pré carregar imagem por imagem com o javascript? Pois vou ter uma pasta com varias imagens que vão ser jogadas por um banco de dados.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "pré carregar"?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida fazer com que ele carregue todas as imagens dessa pasta mas não mostre, ae quando eu aperta em carregar+ que o banco de dados vai fazer puxar essas imagens elas aparecem no mesmo estante sem delay

Comment: Não sei se entendi seu chefe. O propósito do "Carregar mais" é justamente não carregar tudo. Se for pra carregar tudo, não precisaria do "Carregar mais".

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Carregar do Banco de dados só quando estiver 100% tudo carregado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120395/carregar-do-banco-de-dados-s%c3%b3-quando-estiver-100-tudo-carregado)

Comment: @Guerra não é duplicata :) essa é uma pergunta diferente ^^

Comment: Boa Tarde @kaiquemix, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas por acaso você não estaria procurando algo no sentido de Lazy Load? Existe um plugin que chama 'Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery'. Talvez seja isso que procure...

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho por algum motivo esse não resolveu meu problema pois as imagens aparecem depois de Carregar+ com ajax, ae estou querendo tirar o atraso

Comment: O que vc ja tentou? Aqui não fornecemos a solução completa, indicamos o caminho, sua pergunta anterior vc ja foi orientado, de ontem pra hoje tentou algo?

Comment: @Guerra como acima fui orientado a usar tal plugin, porem explique acima o pq de não conseguir usar ele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom vamos lá,

Situação hipotética,

Você tem uma div, onde você vai colocar suas imagens,

Vamos imaginar:

```
<div class='preload'><img src='urlimagem'></div>
```

Nesse caso, ao carregar sua página você vai disponibilizar as imagens nessa div, deixando o preload com um atributo "display:none"

Quando o cliente clicar no +, você pode deixar um gif de load por exemplo:

```
$('.botaoMais').click(function(){
   $('.espacoCarregamento').html('gif de loading');
   var controle = true;
   $('.preload').each(function(){
      if($(this,'img').complete == false){
         controle = false;
      }
   });
   if(controle == true){
   //display block na div das imagens.
   }
   }
});
```

Isso é para dar display block qndo tiver carregado tudo, mas poderia ir dando em 1 por 1 conforme tá carregado.

Acho que é +- isso.

Mas isso é meio complexo pois tem que ficar segurando a execução até ele carregar, acho que o jeito mais facil é usar essa lib:

http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: entendi entendi, no caso vou ter que fazer aparecer esse carregando na div completa em vez de só na imagem, ja que ele carrega 6 blocos de div, ae depois de 1 segundo carrega as imagens de cada bloco

Comment: Pensei numa forma melhor aqui, qndo você carregar sua página já coloca as divs separada em blocos que serão exibidos separadamente, deixa as que não estão visiveis com display none mas deixam elas lá, dai as img vao carregar e quan do clicar no + é só dar um display block e ele já renderiza

Comment: eu faço um json para da um retorno e quando carregar ir aparecendo

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma lib q vai resolver todos seus problemas, se não tiver problema recomendo fortemente usa-la

Comment: então é isso mesmo que eu uso :D, porem como ta vindo do banco de dados da um pequeno delay de 1 segundo ae meu chef está reclamando que não quer delay :/, eu só não coloquei esses efeitos.
da uma olhada aqui somospixel.com/test no PORTFOLIO

Comment: Acho que tive uma ideia, vou fazer um quadro preto com esse icon de carregando do mesmo tamanho da imagem, ae quando a imagem carregar ela aparece ;), ae agora é como vou fazer isso....